# How to get a program to continuously process a method

Tags: java

**My question is:** why doesnt my program repeat itself when processing lines from a text file.

I am writing a class that manages a garage - cars in a garage are put into a stack of no more than 7, and if that is full, they go into a queue of no more than 5. There is method for adding cars manually and one for reading the input of a text file. I have also been given a stackInt class that I am asked to use while creating the stack object. It has only 4 methods, which makes things cumbersome :

```
public interface StackInt<E> {
    E push(E obj);
    E peek();
    E pop();
    boolean empty();
}
```

So I've had to write my code with ways to circumvent not having other useful stack methods. The majority of my methods work as intended: it reads the text file and process it, but it doesnt repeat the cycle of process if, for example, a car is removed from the garage, another car from the queue is supposed to be inserted. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class Garage{
   
   public String line;
   public String stackToString;
   public int position;
   public int numAdded;
   LinkedList<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();
   StackInt<String> stack = new LinkedStack<>();

   public Garage(){
   }
   
   public Garage(String fileName){
      try{
         File file = new File(fileName);
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
         while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
          line = scan.nextLine();
          String[] data = line.split(" ");
          if (data[0].equals("a"))
              arrival(data[1]);
          else if (data[0].equals("d"))
              departure(data[1]);
         }
       }  
      catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println("File not found");
      }
   }
       
   public boolean arrival(String license){
     boolean added = false;
     
     if(numAdded < 7){
         stack.push(license);
         added = true;
     } else if (queue.size() < 5) {
          added = queue.add(license);
          numAdded--;
       }
     if(added){
       numAdded++;
      }
  
      return true;
  }       
   
   public int departure(String license){
     Stack<String> temp = new Stack();
     
     while(!stack.empty()){
         temp.push(stack.pop());
         
     }
     position = temp.indexOf(license);
         temp.remove(license);
     while(!temp.isEmpty()){
         stack.push(temp.pop());
     }
     return position;    
   }
      
   public int numberParked(){
      return numAdded;
   }
   
   public int numberWaiting(){
      return queue.size();
   }
   
   public String toString(){                         
      Stack<String> tempStack = new Stack();
      while (!stack.empty()){
        tempStack.push(stack.pop()); 
        stackToString = tempStack.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""); 
      } 
      while (!tempStack.empty()){
        stack.push(tempStack.pop()); 
      }     
      return "Cars in Garage: " + stackToString + "\n" + "Cars waiting: " + (queue.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
  } 
}
```

What I'm testing with is this:

```
public class GarageTest
{
    public static void main (String [] args) 
   {
      Garage g1 = new Garage("parking.txt");
      System.out.println("Number parked: " + g1.numberParked());
      System.out.println("Number waiting: " + g1.numberWaiting());
      System.out.println("Parking WEB445 ... " + g1.arrival("WEB445"));
      System.out.println("Parking BEA345 ... " + g1.arrival("BEA345"));
      System.out.println(g1);
      System.out.println("Z23YTU departs after " + g1.departure("B12GFT") + " car(s) moved");
      System.out.println(g1);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
 Number parked: 7
    Number waiting: 5
    Parking WEB445 ... true
    Parking BEA345 ... true
    Cars in Garage: Y23456, X12345, B12GFT, Z23YTU
    Cars waiting: W321RE, CVBNMK, DFGHJK, ERTYUI, FGHJKL
    Z23YTU departs after 2 car(s) moved
    Cars in Garage: Y23456, X12345, Z23YTU
    Cars waiting: W321RE, CVBNMK, DFGHJK, ERTYUI, FGHJKL
```

Whats expected on the "cars in garage" line is:

```
DFGHJK CVBNMK R23EWQ W321RE Y23456 X12345 B12GFT Z23YTU 
with the queue on the next line. It's removing a few that have "d", but not filling the garage 
afterward
```

The text file that is being processed (a for arrival, d for departure):

```
a A123TR
a Z23YTU
a Z23YTU
a ERW345
d ERW345
a B12GFT
d a23TR
a X12345
a Y23456
a W321RE
d R23EWQ
a CVBNMK
a DFGHJK
a ERTYUI
a FGHJKL
a GHJKL9
a HJKL98
```

Comment: Q: So what exactly is your question? What exactly do you expect your code to do, that it isn't?

Comment: It's not processing the cars again i.e. if a car leaves, one from the queue should enter the stack

Answer (score 0):

When you say "if a car is removed from the garage, another car from the queue is supposed to be inserted" - where is this logic in your departure() method? There isn't any code in that method that removes a car from the queue?

The behavior you're expecting is missing from your code.

Comment: temp.remove(license);

Answer (score 0):

Your `departure()` does not call the `arrival()` method anywhere in its body, which would add the next car to the garage. When the `departure()` is successful (the return value is valid (not `-1`)) you know that a car has left the garage. Then you can simply use the next car from the queue and add it via the `arrival()` method. And it will fit in the garage because there is now room for the next car.

Comment: Not sure why that didnt compute for me. So something like this in the departure method: while true{ arrival(license)}?

Comment: @Dogwithastick You don't need a `while` loop. Only one car (at most) left the garage.

Comment: @Dogwithastick Try it.

Comment: it's close, but returning "W321RE, Y23456, X12345, null, B12GFT, null, Z23YTU". Tried remove instead of poll - get no such element exception

Comment: @Dogwithastick You should only add one car to the garage when there is actually a car in the queue. If there is none, then obviously you don't have to "arrive" anything.

Comment: Does not compute. Logically, it makes sense that if something departs, I want to push onto the stack a queue.peek(), which retrieves, but does not remove, the head of this queue. and then remove that element from the queue

Comment: @Dogwithastick You can use `pop()` for that, that does remove the element from the queue and returns the value which was removed.

Comment: stack.push(queue.pop());? that returns a no such element exception

Comment: @Dogwithastick Again, only do that when you have cars in the queue. That might not be always the case.

Comment: if(!queue.isEmpty()){
     stack.push(queue.pop());
     }

Comment: @Dogwithastick Close, you have to call the `arrival()` method, because it has additional logic (like increasing the counter). On that matter, you are currently not adjusting `numAdded` when a car departure.

Comment: @Dogwithastick You might want to use a debugger and use single steps to see how the program is executing your methods, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems

Comment: I don't know what arrival needs to process exactly if it has already "arrived"

Comment: if(!queue.isEmpty()){
         arrival(stack.push(queue.pop()));
              
     } Doesnt seem to work

Comment: @Dogwithastick Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616). Use a debugger as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems to find the bug in your application.